# Choosing default browser

Tags: unity, google-chrome, 15.10, settings

I am having problems choosing my default browser. As far as I can tell there are 2 ways to do it, and right now they are conflicting.

What I want: default browser of Google Chrome

Problem:

In unity (Ubuntu 15.10) when I go to `'Settings -> Details -> Default Applications'` and go to the 'Web' drop down I do not have the option of choosing Chrome.

So I tried to use the command `sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser` but selecting Chrome did nothing (i.e. all of the links I open inside other programs like email links or help documentation all still open in the the browser chosen in the drop down menu in settings). So I tried choosing firefox in the terminal instead.

Then I open Chrome and it tells me it is the default browser.

At this point, three different places in my system are saying I have three different default browsers. How do I fix this so that Chrome is default. It seems like the unity settings is most relevant, but how would I get Chrome to show up there?

Thanks in advance, and image below showing the issue

[image: SCREENSHOT]

As requested, this is the output to `update-alternatives --get-selections | grep browser`:

```
gnome-www-browser              auto     /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
infobrowser                    auto     /usr/bin/info
x-www-browser                  manual   /usr/bin/firefox
```